# After installing Marketplace in Eclipse and running it, "Contacting Software Sites" error occurs

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

After installing Marketplace in Eclipse and running it, an error occurred 'An internal error occurred during: "Contacting Software Sites'.

Error log:
An internal error occurred during: "Contacting Software Sites".
Cannot invoke
"org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.Transport.download
(java.net.URI, java.io.OutputStream, org.eclipse.core.runtime.IProgressMonitor)"
because the return value of
"org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.helpers.AbstractRepositoryManager.getTransport()" is null

I think I can solve it by adding Location to Window > Preferences > Install/Update > Available Software Sites. For example, a location involving org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.

However, no matter how much I research, I can't find out which Location I should add, so I leave a question.

my eclipse version : 2021-03 (4.19.0)
java version : 1.8.0_361

Comment: Eclipse 4.19 requires Java 11. It was required starting with 4.17. 4.19 is also 2 years old and 9 releases behind current. If you want to retrieve and install plug-ins online, I suggest you update to a newer version first.